# AppleScript - make new document at location

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create a Numbers' document and then export it to pdf, but my main issue is that the document is created in iCloud and I cannot delete it. To make this new document at a custom location, I'm using `make new document at`, but I can't get the location specifier correct.
I tried to use a path:

```applescript
set downloads to path to downloads folder
```

But I get an error, `"can't make alias "path" to type location specifier"`. And if I try this:

```applescript
set myDocument to make new document at end of downloads
```

I get another error `Can't obtain alias "Users:username:Downloads"`

I don't understand how I can simply create my document at a specific location...

Comment: Try this, inside a tell application Finder: `folder "Downloads" of (path to home folder)`

Comment: Also, if using an 'alias' file reference for a folder, you should end with a colon (e.g. "HDrivename:Users:username:Downloads:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing apples with oranges. The "location" here is merely the front-to-back position among other similar entities, such as documents / windows. You specify the path on disk when you *save* the document in a later step.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. So if I want to delete the document, I first create a file -> make document with file property -> export it -> delete the file ?

Comment: Can you not just make new (without 'file' property) > export > close without saving?

Comment: @Mockman Very likely; I was just answering the part of the question about the location. Sort of an x-y question eh.

Comment: Actually, I was responding to the OP's comment… rhetorically :) And thanks for the answer as that 'location' has vexed me for the longest time. It cleared things up considerably for me.

Comment: Maybe they should have called this a `position` or something less misleading. But that's water over the dam at this point. :)

Comment: Felt more like a water wheel that I was strapped to. Anything would have been an improvement. Even just some useful examples would be helpful but Apple has a certain antipathy towards doing that.

Comment: @Mockman I've been trying to do this, but that makes Numbers reopening the document I created (so if I run this script 10 times, I'll have 10 Untitled files when opening the app). I ended up saving the file as matt said, just to ask the Finder to delete it afterward.

Comment: Are you saying that the documents are not closing before you quit Numbers? Or, that your script closes the unsaved window, you then quit Numbers, then relaunch it and the unsaved (but closed) window opens again? And that those windows weren't closed by quitting Numbers? We need to isolate the issue to better understand it. In my test script, I launch, make new, export, close, quit (with all of this in a repeat loop).

Comment: Hmm… I just enabled Numbers' use of iCloud Drive storage and I'm getting something similar (maybe identical). The doc I explicitly close gets closed but the other one asks if I want to save. Is that something you can uncheck and test? System Preferences > iCloud > iCloud Drive Options… > uncheck Numbers. Alternatively, leave Numbers open because it seems related to launching the app. Alternatively, put 'close documents without saving' before 'make new'.